# Pandas duplicated rows to unique rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']})
```

What I want is to get something like this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1', '2'], 'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']})
```

I had a dataframe like above but I had to do some analysis so I split it using the following code:

```
df2 = pd.concat([Series(row['Id'], row['Name'].split(',')) for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

I'm looking to reverse the code, but I'm stuck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('Id')['Name'].apply(','.join)
```

You may need to reset the index and rename a column, but this should do the main piece of the job.

Comment: Awesome thanks! it works. And yes you need to reset index :)